# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at showRepositories

Tags: javascript

Olá, sou novo e estou tentando consumir uma Api do github para exibir os repositórios de determinada conta. Só que toda vez que tento chamar a class do botão criado da esse erro. Deixarei o código que estou tentando usar abaixo:

```js
function showInformation() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const inputValue = userText.value;

    if (inputValue === "" || inputValue === null) {
      apiContent.innerHTML = `<p class="msg-error">Username field empty</p>`;
    } else {
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputValue}`)
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
          apiContent.innerHTML = `
          <div class="profile-information">
          <div class="container-profile">
            <span class="btn-close">x</span>
            <img class="profile-img" src="${data.avatar_url}" alt="Image perfil" />
            <h1>${data.name}</h1>
            <div class="profile-location">
                <p>${data.location}</p>
            </div>
            <p>${data.bio}</p>
            
            <div class="container-btn">
              <button class="btn-repository">Repository</button>
            </div>
            
            </div>
          </div> `;
        });
    }
  });
}

showInformation();

function showRepositories() {
  const btnRepository = document.querySelector(".btn-repository");
  btnRepository.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("clicou");
  });
}

showRepositories();
```

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, é um problema de sincronia. Você chama as duas funções imediatamente, portanto, quando `showRepositories()` é chamada -- e consequentemente roda a instrução `const btnRepository = document.querySelector(".btn-repository")`, ainda não ocorreu o retorno do `fetch` da função de cima -- portanto, o elemento com a classe `btn-repository` ainda não foi criado. Com isso, a variável `btnRepository` recebe um valor undefined, e na instrução seguinte você tenta adicionar um eventListener nessa variável, que é só um `undefined` (no seu caso, por algum motivo, `null`, mas dá no mesmo).

Comment: Tente mover a última linha, que é a chamada de sua funçao `showRepositories();`, para dentro do último `then`, logo depois das várias linhas da instrução `apiContent.innerHTML = ...monte de coisa...`. Com isso, a função só vai ser rodada depois que o botão existir, e provavelmente o encontrará.

Comment: Po, pensei nisso mas nem pensei em chamar a função dentro. MUITO obrigado

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Opa, tudo certo?

O que fiz diferente do seu foi **retirar o eventListener de dentro das funções** e retornar o resultado da API de maneira individual para cada tag. Na prática, retornar individual ou fazer um `` e colocar tudo lá dentro não muda muita coisa. Fiz assim na intenção de facilitar o entendimento.

Acredito que isto irá te ajudar a resolver seu problema:

```
<body>
    <input id="user" type="text">
    <img id="avatar" src="" alt="">
    <h1 id="name"></h1>
    <p id="bio"></p>
    <button id="callApi">Chamar API</button>
</body>
<script>
    const user = document.getElementById('user');
    const callApi = document.getElementById('callApi');
    const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
    const name = document.getElementById('name');
    const bio = document.getElementById('bio');

    callApi.addEventListener('click', () => {
       if(user.value !== ''){
        fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.value}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const avatarGithub = data.avatar_url;
            const nameGithub = data.name;
            const bioGithub = data.bio;

            avatar.src = avatarGithub;
            name.innerHTML = nameGithub;
            bio.innerHTML = bioGithub;
        })
       } else {
           alert('Digite um usuário válido');
       }
    })
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado!